# JMeter with java.io.IOException: >> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components

Tags: java, jmeter, dns, jmeter-5.0

I need help, i wanto to recorder in JMeter but i cant for the DNSName, but my HTTP is https://www.blazedemo.com/, is a version 5.4.3.
I send now like THIS;

```
C:\>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2 SET PATH=%PATH%;JAVA_HOME\bin
```

But even this appear this error;

```
java.io.IOException:   >> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components must consist of letters, digits, and hyphens <<
Command failed, code: 1
```

'keytool -genkeypair -alias https://www.blazedemo.com/ -dname "cn=https://www.blazedemo.com/, o=JMeter Proxy (TEMPORARY TRUST ONLY)" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted} -keypass {redacted} -validity 7 -ext san=dns:[https://www.blazedemo.com/'](https://www.blazedemo.com/%27)
at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:173) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateSignedCert(KeyToolUtils.java:290) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateHostCert(KeyToolUtils.java:281) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1587) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1480) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:523) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:623) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:463) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.3]
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) ~[?:?]
at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.button.DarkButtonListener.mouseReleased(DarkButtonListener.java:72) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626) ~[?:?]
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) [?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) [?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]

Comment: Please provide the code of the `keytool` command that you issued.

Comment: According to the error message you have an extension `-ext san=dns:https://www.blazedemo.com/`  that contains column `:` and slash `/` while only *letters, digits, and hyphens* are allowed for `dns` type of `san`. Use hostname, not urs for `dns` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) amend `hostToRecord` to be just `blazedemo.com`

[image]

The `hostToRecord` must be a valid [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) and the requirements are:

> The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols specify that labels may contain only the ASCII letters a through z (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits 0 through 9, and the hyphen-minus character ('-'). The original specification of hostnames required that labels start with an alpha character, and not end with a hyphen.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.